# Install Wordpress - Localhost

Tags: localhost

I am following a Lynda.com course to be trained on Wordpress and how to install and configure MAMP and WordPress. Everything has run smoothly until now, however, I have difficulties with finding the setup page for WP. The course tells me to write: "http://localhost/wp-admin/setup-config.php" but nothing happens. As I am a beginner, any clear guidance would be helpful. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "nothing happens"...something has to happen.  Do you get an error, white screen, etc?  Are you sure you have your server running?  What happens when go to just http://localhost/?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The link leads me to Wordpress support page (forum) where a user shared a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have default configuration for Mamp, URL must contains the port number.
http://localhost:8888/